# Getting Master-Detail tables from WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, foreign-key-relationship, master-detail

I have a database with two tables. They have a foreign key relationship (so they have the classical master-detail structure).

I want to fetch the entire data of these two tables using calls to ASP.NET MVC WebAPI from javascript (an Angular app to be specific) in the browser. In JavaScript, I wish to reconstruct the data into objects with the appropriate relationships (so that the detail objects have a reference to the correct master)

What would be the cleanest way to implement this?

One option would be to call the REST API for the master, iterate through the result and make a REST call to get the detail records for each master.
This feels a bit brute-force, and obviously causes a lot of REST calls.

Can I construct a WebAPI call that would be easy to deserialize into the correct object structure in JavaScript? That is appropriately RESTful?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the chatty implementation of making a REST call for each detail.

If you are using entity framework getting all the data in one chunk is as simple as this (the include is needed if you have disabled lazy loading on your entity framework database context):

```
public IEnumerable<Master> Get()
{
   return _context.Masters.Include(m ->m.Details).ToList();
}
```

From angularjs you could easily fetch this using the query method of a $resource.